# How to prevent a yoga mat from skidding?

Tags: home, organization

I have a yoga/exercise mat. But due to tiled flooring, it slips a lot and I find it difficult to do, say, jumping jacks on it.
Any ideas on how to make it stick to the floor?
I tried putting a rug under it. That helps but it still moves.

Comment: Put a [non-slip mat](https://www.amazon.co.uk/Auckpure-Multipurpose-Non-Slip-80X130CM-Waterproof/dp/B08F41ZVYM/) under it.

Comment: Buy a [Amazon.co.uk : yoga mats non slip](https://www.amazon.co.uk/yoga-mats-non-slip/s?k=yoga+mats+non+slip)

Comment: If you only move it occasionally, spray only the mat with a low-grip fabric contact adhesive, e.g., https://swankyden.com/best-spray-adhesive-for-fabric/, *and let it dry before putting mat on floor*, to allow mat to be removed later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have a tiled floor too. The best thing I've found for mats and rugs so far is Ikea's Stopp Filt product (*not* the same thing as the one just called Stopp). This stuff is surprisingly grippy, much more than those mesh/net designs.

Since you have to buy way too much for a single yoga mat, you can just fold it in layers till it works. Or put it under other rugs.

Answer (score 0):

Place a wet towel underneath the mat. I use a wet towel on the shower floor to keep from slipping. the grip is rock solid.